# When to transfer work from Photoshop to inDesign?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, design-process

I'm designing a brochure for the first time. I did everything in Photoshop because I'm much more comfortable with it. But to refine the last layout details, put everything together, and deliver final product to client/printer, I need inDesign.

My question is: what is the best moment for importing Photoshop work into inDesign when designing a brochure or other print stuff?

Comment: Optimally you would *start* in InDesign and place photographs. You wouldn't begin much in Photoshop at all.

Comment: Sure but there is one thing that prevents me from basically doing all in inDesign, it's that it's full of frames and guides everywhere. I just find it messy, Photoshop allows me to concentrate on the final result without being distracted by guides all around. Or is there something I can do about that in inDesign ?

Comment: You can turn off almost all frames and guides in the View menu of InDesign. You can even hit the `W` key to see a print preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Scott. But I think you can still salvage this one.

In my experience it's best to do all your text in InDesign and leave everything else in the external files. InDesign has much better text reproduction when you create the final PDF.

Thankfully InDesign now supports directly linking Photoshop files as images. So when you create your InDesign file just go to File -> Place and place the photoshop file. Go back to Photoshop, turn off all the text layers, save the photoshop file. Go to the Links panel in Indesign (Window -> Links) and double click the yellow warning sign to update the Photoshop file.

Now redo all the text in InDesign. It sounds like a lot of work but you'll be much happier with the result. and this is much closer to what your Photoshop/InDesign workflow should be like.

Answer (score 2):

Well you should only use Photoshop for Image manipulation and should use InDesign for everything else.  So to answer your question the best time to use InDesign is at the beginning and you could always reference a few tutorials or [existing questions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-indesign) we have on it.

Why not take this time, since you have a completed design and try to do everything in InDesign?  Yes it will take you longer but you have to start somewhere.

This might help:

- [Layers Magazine](http://layersmagazine.com/category/indesign)
- [Tuts Plus](http://design.tutsplus.com/series/beginners-guides-to-indesign--vector-4951)
- [40 brilliant InDesign tutorials](http://www.creativebloq.com/graphic-design-tips/indesign-tutorials-1232639)
- [Lynda](http://www.lynda.com/InDesign-training-tutorials/233-0.html)
- [InDesignSecrets](http://indesignsecrets.com/)